# How to pass PHP value to external JavaScript file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, parameters

I am trying to pass my variables from my main page to external JS file. Please see my code.

**Main page:**

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var add_project_link="<?= base_url().'add_project/show_form'; ?>";
var add_agent_link="<?= base_url().'agent/add_agent';?>";
});

</script>
```

**External JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    alert(add_project_link);
    alert(add_agent_link);
  });
```

I got:

> uncaught referenceError add_project_link is not defined.

I thought the external JS would catch the variable declared in main page. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't define your JavaScript variables inside jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){ });` on the main page.  The entire point is to define them BEFORE you call jQuery's external file.  Look at my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Before** you call your external JavaScript file, define your variables using PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var site_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
   var current_url = '<?php echo current_url(); ?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

In your external file.js you can now use `site_url` as a variable.

Comment: I think it `echo` and not `return` you should use to make this code works

Answer (score 5):

Take your php generated variables out of document ready. They are not accessible anyhwere else in your code due to closure of the ready event function they are in

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is to store those variables to something easily called by JS later.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_var" value="<?= base_url().'add_project/show_form'; ?>" />

var add_project_link = $('#hidden_var').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You just write in the head tag

```
<script type="text/javaScript">    
var add_project_link="<?= base_url().'add_project/show_form'; ?>";
var add_agent_link="<?= base_url().'agent/add_agent';?>";
</script>
```

Then load your External JS after the script above

Comment: this is what I have. no luck though. +1

Answer (score 2):

best way is to to store those path in some tags like

```
<span id="site_url" style="display:none;"><?php echo site_url(); ?></span>
<span id="current_url" style="display:none;"><?php echo current_url(); ?></span>
```

then you can access this this using jquery like

```
$('#site_url').html();
$('#current_url').html()
```

Comment: While this technique can work as desired, this advice may be needlessly bloating the DOM with otherwise unnecessary elements/nodes.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest thing to do is to bring the script into a script tag on the php page

you can go down the URL string variable route, but it's unnecessary I think